# SFTP get last created/modified files

Tags: linux, terminal, ftp, sftp

I connect to the server via sftp connection. I should get two files: last created/modified *.sql and *.bkp files.

I've tried something like 
`ls -t >>  list_of_files`
then to download it to my local mashine

```
 get list_of_files
 cat list_of_files | grep *sql | head -1 >> sql_filename
 cat list_of_files | grep *sql | head -1 >> bkp_filename
```

`ls -t >>  list_of_files` outputs 
`Can't ls: "path" not found`

Now i got the names of these two files, how can i get it from the sftp server ?

How can i make it right ?

Comment: use ssh to get the list of files first: `ssh user@server ls -t path/to/files/` and you could even work that up to include the grep and head as well so that it just returns the files you need. i.e. `ssh user@server ls -t /path/to/files/ |grep \*.sql |head -1 >>sql_filename` note: the escape of the * to prevent the local bash from expanding it, so it gets passed to the remote grep intact.

Comment: but how do i do this using sftp ?

Comment: @Cwissy , i get an empty sql_filename when i type `ssh l-one@localhost ls -tl  Desktop/l | grep \*.sql | head -1 >> sql_filename`

Comment: try it in pieces, so first try `ssh l-one@localhost ls -tl Desktop/l` to ensure you do get a directory listing then add the `|grep \*.sql` to just filter sql files and ensure you continue to get output then use the `head -1` part to just get the file you are interested in.

Comment: @Cwissy , yes, it worked thanks, but how do i get the file from the  server via sftp connection when i have just the filename and the location folder ? `variable= $(filename) doesn't work in sftp`

Comment: from `man sftp`: `sftp [user@]host[:file ...] retrieve files automatically if a non-interactive authentication method is used; otherwise it will do so after successful interactive authentication.` so, `sftp l-one@localhost:Desktop/l/$filename` should retrieve the file

Comment: Thanks, that worked !